# DataGrid consuming XML data from URLLoader

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xml-parsing, flash-cs5

I have two functions; `submitIngredientChoices`, that passes variables into a query string to a website called Recipe Puppy in this format: `/?i=chicken,lamb,pesto&q=italian&format=xml`. The website has an open API and returns an XML document.

My second function, `recipeResults()` instantiates a DataGrid with it's dataProvider set to URLLoader data (`loader.data`). The data is loaded into the DataGrid, but it doesn't look very nice and displays some columns as text where I would like them to be hyperlinks.

```
function submitIngredientChoices(event:MouseEvent):void {

    var url : String = 'http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/';
    // url variables all which will appear after ? sign
    var urlVariables : URLVariables = new URLVariables ();
    var ingredients:Array = [so.data.meat1, so.data.meat2, so.data.meat3,
                             so.data.veg1, so.data.veg2, so.data.veg3,
                             so.data.carbs1, so.data.carbs2, so.data.carbs3];

    var others:Array = [so.data.other1, so.data.other2, so.data.other3,
                        so.data.cuisine1, so.data.cuisine2, so.data.cuisine3,
                        so.data.mealtype1, so.data.mealtype2, so.data.mealtype3];

    urlVariables['i'] = ingredients.join();
    urlVariables['q'] = others.join();
    urlVariables['format'] = "xml";

    // creating new URL Request
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest (url);
    // setting the variables it need to carry
    request.data = urlVariables;
    // setting method of delivering variables ( POST or GET )
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    trace(request.data);
    // creating actual loader
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, recipeResults);
    loader.load(request);
}
```

And my datagrid function:

```
function recipeResults(event:Event):void {
    addChild(_dataGrid);
    var xmlDP:XML = new XML(loader.data);
    // create a new data provider with this and register it with the DataGrid
    dp = new DataProvider(xmlDP);
    dataGrid.dataProvider = dp;
}
```

I know that having a `xmlParse` function would be a solution to this, but how has my dataGrid automatically loaded the unparsed XML document without any parsing happening?

I would also like to know how I can adopt my code below to easily change the columns and how I would have the `a href` column of my xml data as a hyperlink?

EDIT: I am more familiar with AS2 but I've just realized that one of the main new features of AS3 is automatic XML parsing (i think that's right isn't it?) Anyway my question still stands, how do I change the look and feel of the datagrid (i.e. how do I access the xml elements and attribute them to a column in the datagrid?)

Comment: Are you using Flex's datagrid?

Comment: @Kodiak No, Flash Professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the columns property on the datagrid to an object containing the string names of the columns you want.

You can find more information on customizing the DataGrid (such as setting the default column width) here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f4a.html

Alternatively you could use E4X to parse the XML into a format that better suits your needs. Here's a tutorial on doing that:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X